# Generalisation of automorphisms on groups of units $U(p^n)$?

Tags: group-theory

I tried to solve the following exercise:

Prove that the mapping from $U(16)$ to itself given by $x \mapsto x^3$ is an automorphism. What about $x \mapsto x^5$ and $x \mapsto x^7$? Generalize.

> Please could someone tell me if my solution is correct?

Because $U(n)$ is commutative the map is operation preserving. Also, because $\gcd(3,16)=1$ it is invertible. Since a homomorphism is an isomorphism if and only if it has a two-sided inverse the map $x \mapsto x^3$ is an isomorphism.

The same argument works for $x^5$ and $x^7$.

Generalization:

On $U(n)$ the map $x \mapsto x^k$ is an isomorphism if $k$ and $n$ are coprime because then it is invertible.

(Note that here $n$ is not necessarily a prime power even though $16$ happens to be a prime power.)

> I'm particularly interested in knowing if my generalization is
>   correct. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thank you for your comment!